# PrimeFaces p:fileUpload Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have a strange problem with the `p:fileUpload` update of PrimeFaces. I upload an image and save it in a database and this is already working.
Here is my code for the `p:fileUpload`.

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{playerController.handleFileUpload}" 
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
        update="messagePanel preview" />
```

After the upload i render a `h:panelGroup` which shows the image.

```
<h:panelGroup id="preview">
    <p:graphicImage value="#{facesContext.externalContext.contextName}/showProfileImage?&amp;preview=true" alt="#{playerController.selected.image.name}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{playerController.selected.image.name}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

In Google Chrome everything is working perfect but in Firefox and Internet Explorer the image does not render when I have already uploaded an image. The old image still appears. After refreshing the page the new image is there.

In FireBug I get this message: "NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED: Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsIDOMLSProgressEvent.input]"

I updated all my browsers to the newest version and I am using PrimeFaces 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra whitespace just before

```
&preview=true
```

in your code. I am emphasizing it using *** * * here:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{facesContext.externalContext.contextName}/showProfileImage?*****&amp;preview=true" alt="#{playerController.selected.image.name}"/>
```

Remove the whitespace and try it. May be FF and IE doesnt like the space and Chrome is linient

Comment: I removed it, but unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing the template/css components you're using in your project? I have kind of the same problem, and I noticed that if i remove all those components it work fine.